# js-tree. The input field after choosing a context menu not appear

Tags: javascript, jstree

After selecting create/rename/etc, the input field should've appeared on any node.

You can right click on any node. The context menu should appear

```html
  <div id="jstree">
    <!-- in this example the tree is populated from inline HTML -->
    <ul>
      <li>Root node 1
        <ul>
          <li id="child_node_1">Child node 1</li>
          <li>Child node 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Root node 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button>demo button</button>
```

this is the reproduction:
https://codepen.io/dhika345/pen/PoqPrgo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't know there is check_callback property. Added to the core property solves it